# How does the song feature work on the Casio CTK keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, beginner

I know the Casio CTK keyboards have 100 songs built in. I have seen several videos on Youtube showing how one can use this to learn the songs. For example, one selects a song and then the keyboard will play parts of the song and wait for you to repeat.

My question is: Is it possible to just listen to the songs? So without it stopping or trying to teach you. I know this is possible on the Casio SA 76 keyboard (but it only has 10 songs).

I looked in the manual and can see that one can start playing the demo songs (by pressing two buttons). What happens if one just selects a song and press just the play button?

Specifically I am interested in the models 2400 and 3200.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: According to http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic one can ask about how to use specific hardware.

Comment: If you are lucky, someone who owns the keyboard you are interested in will weigh in either with a comment or answer.  If not, you might need to dig around on line a little more (Casio website maybe?) or see if they sell those at an on line music store like Sweetwater, Guitar Center, or Zzounds where you can actually speak to a salesman and ask questions about any of the products or instruments they sell.  Good luck.

Comment: FWIW - "hardware" as used in the help topic you referenced is most likely intended to refer to computer hardware used for recording as it appears in the context of software & hardware which would indicate computer.  But I suppose an electronic keyboard such as you described might fit a loose definition of "hardware".  A computer keyboard would certainly fit the definition as would a keyboard controller used in a recording studio.  So your argument has merit despite the fact that your usage falls outside recording studio applications. Hopefully someone will provide the information you seek.

Answer (score 1):

In this respect the CTK boards are exactly the same as the SA 76, except they have a lot more songs to choose from (as you noticed).

So the answer to your question is: Yes.  You can just play them if you want to.